Distribute instances along a curve equidistance on cuve projection on a plane
complete beginner here, so bear with me please!
I would like to create a palisade fence with the help of the geometry nodes. At first sight it seems simple: Curve --> Resample --> instance on points.
Now, my problem is that the fence goes steeply up at one point, and I want the instances to be equidistant on the projection on the horizontal plane to prevent the poles from overlapping each other.
I tried creating a linked object of the curve and shrinkwrapped it on the horizontal plane, but then I'm stuck. I now have the choice of creating a fully horizontal fence with nicely spaced poles (taking the shrink-wrapped linked object as base) or one that goes up and down, but with unevenly spaced poles (taking the original curve as base).
Is it somehow possible to tell Blender to either transpose each instance on the projected curve up to the projection's originator, or to resample the curve with projected equidistance in the first place, or get the required result in yet another way?

if you save the z-position of your original curve, then just set z of your curve to 0, resample by length, then restore old z position and instance your poles:


Wow.... just.... wow..... I cannot express how amazed I am about the versatility of these geometry nodes, and how incredibly fast I got such a great answer to my question, perfectly explaining me how I can solve my problem! THANKS A LOT!!

you are welcome
